# slow query with lots of left joins

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb, query-performance

When I check `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` in database I got below query. It heavily uses CPU (more than 100%), it took 80 seconds to complete the query. We have a separate server for database(64GB RAM).

```
INSERT INTO `search_tmp_598075de5c7e67_73335919` 
SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, MAX(score) AS `relevance` 
  FROM (SELECT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0)) * 1) AS score  
        FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index`
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea`
                    ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` 
                    ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id
        LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `rating`
                    ON `rating`.`entity_pk_value`=`search_index`.entity_id
                   AND `rating`.entity_type = 1
                   AND `rating`.store_id  =  1
       WHERE (category_ids_index.category_id = 2299)
  ) AS `main_select`
 GROUP BY `entity_id`
 ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
 LIMIT 10000
```

why does this query use my full CPU resources?

Comment: Bad or not indexing in the SELECT part maybe we need to see a explain of the select part.

Comment: What are the primary keys of your tables?

Comment: This is an example how queries should not look like.

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ especially the part on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: this query not created by us, this is default Magento query for indexing. is there any mysql configuration setting to overcome this?

Comment: Probably no configuration settings can fix this. Creating indexes may fix it. But there's no way to know what indexes are needed without knowing what indexes are there.

Comment: Can you please tell me where (in which method) this is called in Magento?

Comment: Why `LEFT`?  Why is max_score zero?

Comment: @O.Jones I confirmed creating index fix my problem, now it took milli seconds to complete query.

Answer (score 3):

Some inefficiencies:

- There is a non-null condition on the records of the outer joined `catalog_category_product_index`. This turns the outer join into an inner join. It will be more efficient to use an `inner join` clause.
- There is no need to have a nested query: the grouping, ordering and limiting can be done directly on the inner query.
- `(((0)) * 1)` is just a complex way of saying `0`, and taking the `MAX` of that will obviously still return a relevance of `0` for all records. Not only is this an inefficient way to output `0`, it also makes no sense. I assume your real query has some less evident calculation there, which might need optimisation.
- If `catalog_eav_attribute.attribute_id` is a unique field, then there is no sense in outer joining that table, because that data is not used anywhere
- If `review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value` is unique (at least when `entity_type = 1` and `store_id = 1`), then again there is no use in outer joining that table, because that data is not used anywhere
- If the fields in the above 2 bullet points are non-unique, but the number of records returned per `search_index.entity_id` value is not influencing the result (as it currently stands with the obscure `(((0)) * 1)` value, it does not), then neither outer join is needed either.

With these assumptions, the `select` part can be reduced to:

```
SELECT      search_index.entity_id, 
            MAX(((0)) * 1) AS relevance 
FROM        catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 AS search_index 
INNER JOIN  catalog_category_product_index AS category_ids_index 
        ON  search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id 
WHERE       category_ids_index.category_id = 2299
GROUP BY    search_index.entity_id 
ORDER BY    relevance DESC 
LIMIT       10000
```

I still left the `(((0)) * 1)` in there, but it really makes no sense.